# LDAP down - exim down

Tags: centos, ldap, exim

I need some ideas here:

Centos 5 with ldap authentication loses exim functionality once the ldap server becomes unavailable (in the logfile I can see it just hangs once receives "rcpt to:") , any ideas?

I did try this with no luck:
[Linux console is unusable when LDAP server is down](https://serverfault.com/questions/55724/linux-console-is-unusable-when-ldap-server-is-down)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `exim` receive the message it validate whether the requested user is present in the DB(s) with ACL's verb `verify recipient`. If DB is unavailable then `exim` can't validate and drop the session - not hangs.

You can turn off recipient validation, but that is not wise choice.
If you have used remote LDAP source, you can replicate it on the local machine an use local copy instead of remote.
If you have used local LDAP, then you have to investigate why did your LDAP becomes unavailable.

Comment: thanks for your reply. the usage of ldap was initially only for login to the server, so removing exim's usage would make scene..?

Comment: If no LDAP users have mail accounts, then you can easily exclude LDAP from exim's config.

Comment: ..how do i do that? can't find that setting in exim.conf

Comment: ..or shouldn't I exclude exim from LDAP?

Comment: ..Anyone with an idea?